# Is GetTypeInfo missing in .NETCore 4.5.1?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I try to read an embedded resource (a font file in a Windows 8.1 Store App) as a Byte stream, but the Problem is the Access to the resource file. I often use

```
typeof(Type).GetTypeInfo.Assembly.GetMainfestResourceStream(...)
```

but the method `GetTypeInfo()` in the System.Reflection.Type of .NETCore v.4.5.1 doesn´t exist. Is a Lib-Reference-missing? I´m a little confused ^^

Comment: It is an extension method, adding `using System.Reflection;` is required to let the compiler recognize it.

Comment: That was too simple ^^

Comment: Please check the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> It is an extension method, adding `using System.Reflection;` is required to let the compiler recognize it.

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)

Comment: ... and check that your project's <TargetFramework(s)> actually mentions net451 and not e.g. net40. The error message `... (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` in the later case is a bit misleading.